# Operand should contain 1 column(s) - by copying a row at the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to copy a row inside the same table, by selecting all columns except `id` which is `autoincrement`

```
   $stmt = $db->query(
    "insert into banners (date, src, pos, format, inde, link) 
    select (date, src, pos, format, inde, link) from banners 
    where id = " . $id);
```

`$id` is an integer (checked).

Error:
`Operand should contain 1 column(s)...`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is without brackets:

```
insert into banners (date, src, pos, format, inde, link) 
select date, src, pos, format, inde, link from banners 
where id = ?
```

(also try to use prepared statements with placeholders on your query)

Comment: Thanks, there is no error now, but the row is not copied at all, have you any idea - why?

Comment: Does the ID you put in the place of the questionmark(or supplied via prepared statement) exist?